# Not getting the right answer in this limit with absolute value

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

$\lim_{x \to a} \dfrac{\sqrt{ax}-|a|}{ax-a^2}$ , a<0

im getting:

$\lim_{x \to a} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{ax}+a}$
So my final answer is:
$\dfrac{1}{|a|+a}$

But the right answer is:
$\dfrac{1}{2|a|}$

Im not sure why, can you help me please?

Comment: I would double check where your assumption that $a < 0$ comes into play, because with $a<0$ you get $|a| + a = 0$, which is problematic when you have $\frac{1}{|a| + a}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be
$$
\lim_{x \to a} \dfrac{\sqrt{ax}-|a|}{ax-a^2}=
\lim_{x \to a} \dfrac{\sqrt{ax}-|a|}{ax-a^2}\cdot\dfrac{\sqrt{ax}+|a|}{\sqrt{ax}+|a|}=\lim_{x \to a} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{ax}+|a|}=\frac{1}{2|a|}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\sqrt{ax}-|a|}{ax-a^2} = \frac{\sqrt{ax}-|a|}{(\sqrt{ax}-|a|)(\sqrt{ax}+|a|)} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{ax}+|a|}$$
Now take the limit as $x\rightarrow a$.  The above expression approaches $\displaystyle\frac{1}{2|a|}$.